# python3 option to change default traceback format

Tags: python, error-handling

I there an option to enable "standard format" for python traceback. Ie, instead of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./make_directory.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It should look like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
./make_directory.py:7: error
7 | data = json.loads(sys.argv[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am looking for a solution that does not require any changes to the script in this. In this case `make_directory.py`.

Comment: just curious, why do you want this?

Comment: If the script has been started inside an IDE, it would certainly help to parse the error message.